# Loopback interface name on rhel 7 (and onwards)

Tags: java, networking, rhel7

If I run `ifconfig` command on my rhel7 machine I see below output:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet x1.x2.x3.x4  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx
        inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx::xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
lo:1: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet x5.x6.x7.x8  netmask 255.255.255.255
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

Questions:
My objective is to just get the local IPs only for this machine. E.g. it's `x1.x2.x3.x4` in above example (it can be more than one, if more NICs are installed).

1. do the name of the local loopbacks always start with lo for all the rhel 7 + versions?
2. how to just get the local IPs using the java program. I looked at sample codes on stackoverflow, but nothing conclusive. I always seem to be getting `x5.x6.x7.x8` as well. But I don't want `x5.x6.x7.x8` as it's not an IP of the NIC. It's a virtual IP.

Comment: This isn't Java-related and, while not *quite* off-topic, would probably get better answers on Unix/Linux SE.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I posted it on Unix/Linux SE. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606844/loopback-interface-name-on-rhel-7-and-onwards